# Insert Records that are not exists in Target Table and delete records that are not exists in source dataset Using MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I have a table With data like below (`Table 1`)

```
id          valueId     Value
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           1           Value 1
1           1           Value 2
1           1           Value 3
1           2           Value 1
1           2           Value 2
1           2           Value 3
```

And i have another dataset like below (`DataSet`)

```
id          valueId     Value
----------- ----------- -------
1           1           Value 1
1           1           Value 2
1           1           Value 4
```

now i need to insert records that are not exists in the `Table 1` (You can see the record

```
id          valueId     Value
----------- ----------- -------
1           1           Value 4
```

is not in the `Table 1`, that record should insert) and need to delete records from `Table 1` that are not in `DataSet` which is

```
id          valueId     Value
----------- ----------- -------
1           1           Value 3
```

, but without affecting other records (other records means records that `id=1 and valueId=2`).

I have used the following T-SQL that i have wrote it using `MERGE`, It inserts the missing records but it deletes all the records that are not in the `DataSet`

```
DECLARE @tmp_value AS TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      valueId INT ,
      [Value] NVARCHAR(50)
    ) ;
INSERT  @tmp_value
        ( [id], [valueId], [Value] )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, N'Value 1' ),
        ( 1, 1, N'Value 2' ),
        ( 1, 1, N'Value 3' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 1' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 2' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 3' ) ;

--SELECT  *
--FROM    @tmp_value AS TV ;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 1' AS [Value]
               UNION
               SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 2' AS [Value]
               UNION
               SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 4' AS [Value]
             )
    MERGE @tmp_value AS TV
        USING cte
        ON [cte].[id] = [TV].[id]
            AND [cte].[valueId] = [TV].[valueId]
            AND [cte].[Value] = [TV].[Value]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED 
            THEN INSERT VALUES   ( id , [valueId] , [Value] )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
            THEN DELETE ;

SELECT  *
FROM    @tmp_value
```

**Expected Result:**

```
id          valueId     Value
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           1           Value 1
1           1           Value 2
1           1           Value 4
1           2           Value 1
1           2           Value 2
1           2           Value 3
```

Comment: You can do `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.[Value] = TV.[Value])` but probably better to just use two statements.

Comment: @SAM : There is a mistake in updated question. Update and delete rows just got swapped.

Comment: @SAM : Why last row ( 1, 2, N'Value 3' ) is not eligible for delete ?

Comment: @RaviSingh no its not, because the ValueId is different.

Comment: @SAM : Does this mean that each row of the dataset will have same [id] and [valueid] ?

Comment: no, it can have deferent `ValueId` For a `ID`. for ex: if the dataset had `row ( 1, 2, N'Value 3' )` we can delete `row ( 1, 2, N'Value 2' )` and `row ( 1, 2, N'Value 1' )` from `Table 1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29516/discussion-between-sam-and-ravi-singh)

Answer (score 1):

**Update :**

```
DECLARE @tmp_value AS TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      valueId INT ,
      [Value] NVARCHAR(50)
    ) ;
INSERT  @tmp_value
        ( [id], [valueId], [Value] )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, N'Value 1' ),
        ( 1, 1, N'Value 2' ),
        ( 1, 1, N'Value 3' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 1' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 2' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 3' ) ;

--SELECT  *
--FROM    @tmp_value AS TV ;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 1' AS [Value]
               UNION
               SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 2' AS [Value]
               UNION
               SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 4' AS [Value]
              )
    MERGE @tmp_value AS TV
        USING cte
        ON [cte].[id] = [TV].[id]
            AND [cte].[valueId] = [TV].[valueId]
            AND [cte].[Value] = [TV].[Value]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED 
            THEN INSERT VALUES   ( id , [valueId] , [Value] )
        ;


WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 1' AS [Value]
               UNION
               SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 2' AS [Value]
               UNION
               SELECT   1 AS id , 1 AS valueId , 'Value 4' AS [Value]
             )
    MERGE @tmp_value AS TV
        USING cte
        ON ([cte].[id] = [TV].[id]
            AND [cte].[valueId] = [TV].[valueId]
           AND [cte].[Value] = [TV].[Value])
            or not( [TV].[id] in (select distinct id from cte)
            and [TV].[valueId] in (select distinct valueid from cte))
        WHEN NOT MATCHED 
            THEN INSERT VALUES   ( id , [valueId] , [Value] )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source 
            THEN DELETE ;

SELECT  *
FROM    @tmp_value
```

Comment: i'm sorry i think i did a mistake in my question. ill edit. im not only considering about the `Value` Column im considering all the Columns.

Comment: Then your own query is correct as rows ( 1, 1, N'Value 3' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 1' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 2' ),
        ( 1, 2, N'Value 3' ) are not matching and should be removed.

Comment: we have to use two statement is it?

Comment: hmm.. i wanted to do it in a single `MERGE` statement. if we using two statement, we don't need a `MERGE` we could do it using a simple `JOIN` statement